# Communication between sibling controllers

Tags: angularjs

In one of my interview question, this question has been asked to me.
I had given all angular possible answer, but still my interviewer did not satisfy with my answer.

My Solution was

1. Using factory or services in angular.
2. Using `$rootScope`.
3. Using event `$broadcast` and `$emit` and `$on`.

Please help me finding fourth solution.

Thanks
Kusum

Comment: Please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18245760/2106876

Comment: Prototypical inheritance from object in parent controller.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer, most likely, was to use the `require` syntax on a directive. And have the controllers bound to directives, as opposed to being stand along controllers. This is typically considered best practice now. If you're looking for employment in the angular world, you should look up John Papa's style guide. It's pretty much the holy grail of angular best practices.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I agree with your answer given above, but this solution works in case we have controller attached to our respective directive.

but suppose, if i am not using directive and suppose i have two controllers, ctrl1 and ctrl2, then what is the solution to make contollers communicating.